# Net HTTP Persistent / Keep Alive with Ruby OAuth2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, keep-alive

I'm trying to figure out how to enable HTTP keep alive using the [OAuth2 gem](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2). Oauth2 is built on Faraday, which does appear to have experimental [support using net-http-persistent](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday/blob/master/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http_persistent.rb). The only way I can find to enable it in Faraday is to use:

```
Faraday.default_adapter = :net_http_persistent
```

I have a few questions:

1. Is enabling it in Faraday in turn enabling it for Oauth2?
2. Is there anyway to test whether HTTP keep alive is actually working and enabled?

Comment: So, does enabling the adapter in ruby turn on keep-alive? Does that setting need to be done before instantiating a connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ruby, but I believe you can test general http keep-alive settings by running [TCPview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) on a windows machine and monitoring the connection state. (very useful program)

There is also this post on serverfault that discusses monitoring it from the server end: https://serverfault.com/questions/305388/how-to-test-keep-alive-is-working-on-client-end

If you are really paranoid about testing it, you should be able to see the keep alive bits in the http headers by viewing the connection stream with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), but that might be a bit overkill.

Ps. I Saw that your team won the HACK-VT thing and decided to look you up due to your awesome Ruby presentations. Glad I could actually answer something!

Comment: I guess my question wasn't really Ruby-specific anyway. Thanks for the links!